# Why it is "he was promoted to writing" instead of "...to write"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> His first big break in journalism came when he was promoted to **writing** obituaries for the local newspaper.

Why that position is "writing", I think it must be "write".

Comment: to is a preposition here, not part of an infinitive

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259496/when-should-i-use-to-do-and-to-doing

Answer (score 1):

**It changes the meaning**

> Promoted to [writing obituaries]

He was promoted and after the promotion writes obituaries.

> Promoted [to write obituaries]

He was promoted specifically so that he could write obituaries.

Here, "to write obituaries" is the reason for promotion. Previously, there was no reason given and "writing obituaries" could have been a coincidental job in his role.

Comment: What about [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promoted+to+writing%2C+promoted+to+write&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpromoted%20to%20writing%3B%2Cc0)? 
Ngrams not found: promoted to write

Comment: @MvLog - that just means no one has bothered to write _"promoted to write."_  It isn't a common sentiment, but it is perfectly grammatical, and would be understood. Aric's explanation of the difference between the two phrases is exactly correct